# This expression is always a perfect square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

How to show that for $x,y\in \Bbb R$,  the  expression $xy+\left(\frac{x-y}{2} \right)^2$ is always a perfect square?

For example $x=7, y=3$, $7\times 3+\left(\frac{7-3}{2} \right)^2=25=5^2$

Comment: Yes, because it equals $(\frac{x+y}{2})^2$. But wait, $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: All non-negatives are perfect squares among reals, so all you need to show is the expression is never negative by completing the square. Is that really your question?

Answer (score 3):

Expand out the square term, add it to the $xy$ term and factorise the result. You'll find it comes to $((x+y)/2)^2$, which is a perfect square if $x=y\mod 2$

Answer (score 3):

$$xy+\left(\frac{x-y}{2} \right)^2\\
=\frac{4xy+x^2+y^2-2xy}{4}\\
=\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2$$